# How to open up a JAR in a Linux GUI application?

Tags: linux, command

what is a linux command to open .jar file in gui mode in linux so that I can see inside the .jar file by double click?

Gui for .jar file should open so that i can see inside the .jar file.

Comment: Refer to [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/322458/how-to-open-jar-file-using-open-jdk).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just unzip the JAR file (using standard "unzip") or you can use `gnome-open` to look inside.